# Unexpected NameError ONLY when using Atom editor

Tags: python, atom-editor, nameerror, hydrogen

I wrote some code for a Python homework assignment and it's running fine in Mu-editor and other IDE's, but not in the Atom editor (using the Hydrogen package to run it), where it gives me an unexpected NameError. I've already posted this issue in the Atom Github, but I'm not getting a response. The code:

```
theBoard = {'top-L': ' ', 'top-M': ' ', 'top-R': ' ',
            'mid-L': ' ', 'mid-M': ' ', 'mid-R': ' ',
            'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': ' '}


def printBoard(board):
    print(board['top-L'] + '|' + board['top-M'] + '|' + board['top-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['mid-L'] + '|' + board['mid-M'] + '|' + board['mid-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['low-L'] + '|' + board['low-M'] + '|' + board['low-R'])


turn = 'X'
for i in range(9):
    printBoard(theBoard)
    print('Turn for ' + turn + '. Move on which space?')
    move = input()
    theBoard[move] = turn
    if turn == 'X':
        turn = 'O'
    else:
        turn = 'X'


printBoard(theBoard)
```

The NameError I get when trying to run this code:

> ----> 1 printBoard(theBoard)
> NameError: name 'theBoard' is not defined

It throws this error in line 1 of the for loop `printBoard(theBoard)`

I've played around with formatting and shortening `theBoard` in case the formatting of the dictionary was the problem, but that did not change anything. `theBoard` is stored in the global scope (right?), so `printBoard` should be able to call it in the for loop.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: There are no problems with the code itself.

Comment: Please do not post images or screenshots of errors. Format them as code instead.

Comment: Are you sure you ran the lines that contain the definition of `theBoard` before you tried to run the later lines? What does `'theBoard' in globals()` give?

Comment: I don't use Atom and don't know how it works, but looking at the error message, it seems that you're running IPython cells (or some Jupyter notebook), and the line number in the error message is 1, so it looks like you're just running the last line of your script alone. Might it be that you ran the part defining `printBoard` before, and not the one the one creating `theBoard`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thank you for your comment, this solved my problem in the end! I was indeed not running all the lines, because of changes I made in the short cuts used by Hydrogen. Silly I didn't connect the two, because I messed around with Hydrogen not too long ago. I was too focused on the code I guess.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thank you for the revision of my post, I will take the changes you made to heart for any futures posts. You were right about Hydrogen/Atom not running all the lines in the right order. I've made changes in Hydrogen and now it is working properly.